# Query a specific playlist by id

Tags: graphql, spotify

How do you query a specific Spotify playlist by ID?

This doesn't work:

```
query getPlaylist ($id: String!)  {
  spotify {
    me {
      playlists(id: $id) {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query variables:

```
{
  "id": "5EpTRIeVs55Hl1g7NY53v1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [public Spotify graphQL API](https://spotify-api-graphql-console.herokuapp.com/) the required arguments are `id` and `userId`

Here is a working example:

```
{
    playlist(id: "..." , userId: "...") {
        id
        name
        description
        public
        ...
    }
}
```